# Why doesnt my @html.actionlink go to the correct link?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, html.actionlink

Im having a problem with going to the correct link. When im trying to go to index view in template folder it goes to index view in admin folder instead and i cant understand why when the code says it should look for this view in this specific folder:

```
<fieldset>

<legend>SiteConfig</legend>
<p>Create new or edit Customers, Projects etc:   
    @Html.ActionLink("Create", "Add", "Admin", string.Empty) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "AddEdit", "Admin", string.Empty)
</p>
<p>Create new or edit Users:
    @Html.ActionLink("Create", "Add", "Admin", string.Empty) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "AddEdit", "Admin", string.Empty)
</p>
<p>Upload or change Logo:
    @Html.ActionLink("Upload", "Add", "Admin", string.Empty) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Change", "AddEdit", "Admin", string.Empty)
</p>
<p>Upload or change Template:
    @Html.ActionLink("Upload", "Index", "Template", string.Empty) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Change", "AddEdit", "Admin", string.Empty)
</p>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are most probably calling the wrong overload. What is that `string.Empty` for?

Is `Admin` a controller and if so then you can just simple do a

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create", "Add", "Admin")
```

Are you trying to add some html styling to your links, then do this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create", "Add", "Admin", new { @class = "some-class-name"} )
```

Are you trying to pass some parameters

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create", "Add", "Admin", new { @id = 5}, null )
```

Comment: dont know what why my colleges used string.empty for, but it worked using a normal <a href> instead of actionlink

Comment: It will definitely work with an href, I think no doubt about it as long as the url is correct of course. So with your question, if the `Admin` is a controller and `Add` is a method then just remove the `string.Empty` - it does not server any purpose. If your colleague asked you why you removed it then ask him why he added it in the first place - then everything can get cleared ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't completely clear, but for the links you provided, always `Admin` is set as a controller name (third parameter). So in all of your links, the `Add` or `AddEdit` method will be called in the `Admin` controller, and therefore always the `Add` or `AddEdit` template will be used from the `Views/Admin` folder.

Comment: What Andras said was practically correct the syntax for actionlink is {"string text","Action ","Controller",{Parameters}}. also when I am trying to go to a different controller passing a parameter, i always add a **null** parameter at the end. Just added info in case you encounter it also.